# In node.js how to restart the server while handling some exception in uncaughtException

Tags: node.js, uncaught-exception

In my application im using uncaughtException to handle the application error.In this how can i restart the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [forever module](https://npmjs.org/package/forever).

```
npm install forever
```

`forever` will restart your server any time it quits, for any reason.

This means you can do a `process.exit();` in your code any time you want the server to restart.

You'll need a start and stop script to engage forever.

A typical start script would look like this.

```
#!/bin/sh
./node_modules/forever/bin/forever \
 start \
 -al log.forever \
 -ao log.traffic \
 -ae log.errors \
app.js
```

A typical stop script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
./node_modules/forever/bin/forever stop app.js
```

In your exception handling code would look something like this:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    process.exit();
});
```

Comment: can u tell me how to call the forever method.

Comment: process.exit(); //this will restart my server.for this i have to install forever am i right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the built in [nodejs cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) feature. With this module, you set up a master and a few workers, and when a worker die, you can spawn a new one. An example from a recent project of mine:

```
var cluster = require('cluster'),
numCpus = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    for (var i = 0; i < numCpus; i++) {
        console.log("Spawning worker...");
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        console.log("Worker " + worker.pid + " died");
        var newWorker = cluster.fork();
        console.log("Spawning new worker " + newWorker.pid);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forever works well and is simple to setup

You could also try [fleet](https://github.com/substack/fleet) by substack. Fleet makes it really easy to deploy your code to one or many servers. Then you can spawn your server processes using `fleet spawn -- node ...` and fleet will automatically restart any processes that crash